# About use C#(in vs2015) develop android(error:Cannot find monoandroid assembly directory.)

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2015

Don't create  project!!
if i can do that ,will appear the error

**vs2015--android**

[image]

Comment: Have you even installed Xamarin bits properly?

Comment: I don't problem. I have problem same you. Because Xamarin update new version.It can not reference when create new project.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont have previous version of xamarin installed, go to step 4

1. open **Control Panel** > **Programs and Features**, remove **Xamarin** and **Xamarin Android Player**
2. open the **Windows Explorer** and browser to **C:\Users{current_user}\AppData\Local\ **and remove all folder associate with **Xamarin**
3. restart laptop (to clean registry)
4. open **Control Panel** > **Programs and Features**, choose the **Visual Studio 2015** item, and click **Change**.
5. Select **Cross-Platform Mobile Development** > **C#/.NET (Xamarin).** and continue

**note**: the Xamarin installed using VS may not be the latest version. if you follow the guide from msdn to check Xamarin update (Tools > Options > Xamarin > Other, check now), VS will download and update Xamarin again.
In addition, in-built emulator is not working for my machine, need to re-install Xamarin Android Player.

src: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/74423/where-can-we-download-monoandroid-reference-assembly-directory#latest